# Recursive function returns a nan (c++)

Tags: c++, recursion, return

when i use a while loop, the function returns a correct value, but when I make the function recursive, it returns a nan. For debugging purposes, I cout-ed the value(x) just before returning it and it gives a correct answer, but after returning the value to the calling function, it's a nan. One other thing, the program doesn't take 0 for the coefficients of x. Any attempts result in nan. Below is my code (all of it just to be sure I didn't give insufficient information):

```
// This is my first useful program
// to calculate the root (Solution) of exponential
// functions up to the fourth degree using
// Newton-Raphson method and applying a recursive function
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

// Below is the function fGetRoot's prototype declaration
// c4, c3, etc are the coefficients of x in the 4th power, 3rd power
// etc, while c is the constant

float fGetRoot (float c4, float c3, float c2, float c1, float c);
float fPowerFunc(float fPowered, int iPower);
float x;    // declaring this as global variables so they can be initialized in the calling function
int i=10;  //  and be used in the recursive function without being reinitialized during each recursion


int main()
{
    float c4, c3, c2, c1, c;
    float fRoot;

    cout << "Hello, I am a genie for calculating the root of your problems\
up to the fourth power" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the values of the coefficients of x to the power 4\
, 3, 2, 1 and the constant respectively" << endl;

    cout << "x^4:" << endl;
    cin >> c4;
    cout << "\n x^3:" << endl;
    cin >> c3;
      cout << "x^2:" << endl;
    cin >> c2;
    cout << "\n x:" << endl;
    cin >> c1;
      cout << "Constant, C:" << endl;
    cin >> c;
    cout << "\nEnter the initial iteration. Any figure is fine. The closer to the answer, the better" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    i=10; // gets the number of times to iterate. the larger, the more accurate the answer
    fRoot = fGetRoot(c4, c3, c3, c1, c);
    cout <<"\nAnd the root is: " << fRoot << "\n";

    return 0;
}


// The fGetRoot function

float fGetRoot(float c4, float c3, float c2, float c1, float c)
{
    float fTemp1, fTemp2, fTemp3, fTemp4;

    // the series of lines below are equivalent to the one line below but clearer
    fTemp1 = c4*fPowerFunc(x,4);
    cout << "This is the value of c4*x^4: "<< fTemp1 << endl; // for debugging purposes
    fTemp2 = c3*fPowerFunc(x,3);
    fTemp3 = fTemp2 + fTemp1;
    fTemp1 = c2*fPowerFunc(x,2);
    cout << "This is the value of c2*x^2: "<< fTemp1 << endl; //for debugging purposes
    fTemp2 = c1*fPowerFunc(x,1);
    fTemp4 = fTemp1 + fTemp2 + c;
    fTemp1 = fTemp3 + fTemp4;
    fTemp2 = 4*c4*fPowerFunc(x,3);
    fTemp3 = 3*c3*fPowerFunc(x,2);
    fTemp4 = fTemp2 + fTemp3 + 2*c2*x;
    fTemp2 = fTemp4;
    fTemp3 = fTemp1/fTemp2;
    fTemp1 = fTemp3;
    fTemp2 = x - fTemp1;
    x = fTemp2;
    i--;

    // The line below is equivalent to the "fTemp" series of lines... just to be sure

//x=x-(c4*fPowerFunc(x,4)+c3*fPowerFunc(x,3)+c2*fPowerFunc(x,2)+c1*fPowerFunc(x,1)+c)/(4*c4*fPowerFunc(x,3)+3*c3*fPowerFunc(x,2)+2*c2*x);

    cout << "\nThis is x: " << x << endl;
    i--;
    if(i==0)
        return x;
    x=fGetRoot(c4, c3, c2, c1, c); // Let the recursion begin...

}

// A simpler approach to the fPowerFunc(). This gets two numbers and powers the left one by the right one. It works right
float fPowerFunc(float fPowered, int iPower)
{
    float fConstant=fPowered;
    while(iPower>0)
    {
        fPowered *=fConstant;
        iPower--;
    }
    return fPowered;
}
```

Comment: Just curious: Why do you need to do `i--` twice? Before `cout` and after `cout`?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that bug until now!

Answer (score 4):

You simply forgot to `return x` at the end of the function.  It's possible for the compiler to hold temporaries in the register that would hold the return value and make it appear to work.

You should compile with more warnings enabled so the compiler can tell you about things like this.

Comment: He is using a global `float` . Is `return` necessary in that case?

Comment: @VusP He's using the return value in `main()`, so yes

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand where I forgot to return x . The i variable is supposed to count down the number of recursions. when i==0; is when it's supposed to return the value of x. but even so, i get a "control reaches end of non-void function" warning. Thanks.

Comment: @Amani When `i==0` the *innermost* `gGetRoot()` returns  Control returns to the level where `i` had been 1 and you had recursed.  Now execution continues after the call and needs to return again.  If you step through it with a debugger you should see that moment where `i==0` and look at the call stack.  Each of those levels needs to return.

Comment: or simply: `return fGetRoot(c4, c3, c2, c1, c);`  It's tidier than using a global.  If you really do want to use the global value, why do you `return x;` when `i==0`?

Answer (score 2):

And another problem is in this statement: `if(i==0)`, it should be replaced by by `if(i<=0)`.

In float realm there is no concept of equality strictly speaking. Number in a range is more correct abstraction. For example to test if `f` is approximately zero you would do this: 
`if(f >= -epsilon && f <= epsilon) ...` 
Where `epsilon` is either standard [FLT_EPSILON](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Floating-Point-Parameters.html) or some other app specific precision constant.

Comment: `In float realm there is no concept of equality strictly speaking.` Strictly speaking, of course there is. It just doesn't do what you think in the presence of computers that exist in the real world